# Is it possible to use Node JS App Engine Standard Environment with basic scaling to execute a long running task?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I would like to perform some video processing task which can take a long time to complete.

I had thought of using Cloud functions but I found that it can run for a maximum time of 540 seconds.

Browsing the internet, I find that App Engine can be used to execute long running processes.

I need the 'scale to zero' functionality, so, I cannot use Flexible environment.

On https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments, I find that 'Maximum request timeout' in standard environment is 60 seconds.

Is there a way to execute long running task in standard environment?

Comment: This is what node.js is build for asynchronous I/O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview#app_engine_queues)

> all workers must send an HTTP response code (200-299) to the Cloud
>   Tasks service before a deadline based on the instance scaling type of
>   the service: 10 minutes for automatic scaling or up to 24 hours for
>   manual scaling.